# Generic concept of extends and super

Tags: java, list, generics

What is the concept behind the Generic extend that why is it not allowed to modify the 
list; why does it throw a compile time error when I add a string to list , since String extends Object and should be legal.

If this gives compilation error , then what is the use of that list that is created then.

```
         List<? extends Object>  ls=new ArrayList<String>();
         ls.add("asd");  // compilation error
```

And it compiles in the case of super.

```
         List<? super Integer> ls1=new ArrayList<Object>();
         ls1.add(1);
```

I have read Kathy Sierra and Javadoc, but am not able to understand what this means. Please give me a detailed explanation with examples to understand this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs

Comment: i already read that , that doesnt explain why add method is allowed on super and not on extends.

Comment: If you read the answer, it does explain it.

Comment: hmm at runtime any object can come up , then how super works , it is not understandable to me :/

Answer (score 2):

You can't add Strings to a `List<? extends Object>` because ? could be anything.

If you want to put things *into* a list, its type parameter should be a superclass of the type you want to put in. (This includes the type itself.)

If you want to get things *from* a list, its type parameter should be a subclass of the type you want to take out. (This includes the type itself.)

This can be remembered with the acronym PECS - producer-extends, consumer-super.

Comment: so this kind of list can only be used in arguments , not to instantiate so that we can add objects into it , right ??

Comment: ? cant be anything , i typed it safe as <String>

Comment: You can create and initialize a reference a List<? extends Object>, as you have above. You can use it as an argument or elsewhere. You can't add an item through this reference, because the parameterized type *of the reference's type* could be Object or any subclass. You've assigned a List<String> to the reference, but typechecking is checking the type of the reference, not the type of the object to which it points at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler does not care try to analize what actual generic type of list is, it checks only `ls` declared generic type. It is the same as here

```
void add(List<? extends Object> ls) {
   ls.add("1");
   ...
```

`ls` can be eg a list of Integers, you cannot add "1" to it.

Similar explanation applies to `super`